# Wait after request to send another one in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spotify

I'm using spotify WEB API, and the idea is to update the html with the song name when I click the next song button.

The problem is that when I click the button, it does update the song, but updates to the last one playing, instead of the current one.

I tried using other ways, such as the "success" and "complete" parameters, but when using the "complete" it wouldn't update and on the "success" the same would happen.

Is there anyway I can set a "wait" time for the next request to be made?

```
document.getElementById('skip-song').addEventListener('click', function(){
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url:'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/next',
    headers: {'Authorization': "Bearer " + access_token},
    }).done(function(data){
      $.ajax({
        url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/currently-playing',
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token
        },
      }).done(function(response){
            currentPlayingPlaceholder.innerHTML = currentPlayingTemplate(response);
    });
  });
}, false);
```

Comment: In general, it is almost always a good idea to not mix up vanilla JS and jQuery. If you use jQuery and AJAX, then use jQuery everywhere: `$("#previous-song").click(function() { ... })` for event, `$currentPlayingPlaceholder.html(...)` for changing HTML etc.

Comment: really not clear what problem is. Second request won't be made until first one completes. But you don't do anything with data returned from the first

Comment: Your approach looks fine to me, the only thing I noticed is, you're missing `type: 'POST'` in your second request

Comment: question says "when I click the _next_ song button." and yet the code is all about the "previous" song. Is it a typo, or a logical error in the code?

Comment: So is the problem here that your second request is made and answered before the Spotify API recognizes there has been a change to the currently playing song?

Comment: Sorry guys! I copyed the previous song code, but the same happens whether whenever I change songs.

The issue is that the call for the song name is done before spotify api has acknowledged that the song has changed, so it sends the info for the last song. What I needed was a way to call the method that returns me the song info after a while, when the song info has changed on spotify server already

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev i didn't knew I could do it like that! Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By introducing a timeout you can wait a few seconds before requesting the currently playing song.  I do not know how long you should wait, and it feels a little `hacky`.  Would have been nice if the skip functions returned currently playing...

```js
document.getElementById('previous-song').addEventListener('click', function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/previous',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': "Bearer " + access_token
    },
  }).done(function(data) {
    setTimeout(
      $.ajax({
        url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/currently-playing',
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token
        },
      }).done(function(response) {
        currentPlayingPlaceholder.innerHTML = currentPlayingTemplate(response);
      }), 3000); //wait 3 seconds before updating the currently playing
  });
}, false);
```